# Populating ListView with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences

I have an application that saves a list of query tags for youtube searches.  The user inputs a search in an editText in the Main activity and when the user presses the save button, that search is saved in a ListView in a ListActivity.  The problem is when I close the application and open it up again the saved searches are gone.  I used SharedPreferences to save the search but am unable to get my ListView to populate it with the saved searches.  Can someone give me some direction on how to retrieve the data saved in my ListView using SharedPreferences?  My code is below.

```
//This is the Main Activity
public class Main extends Activity {


    Button save;
    EditText text;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //NEW



        final WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        browser.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Button buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        Button buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        Button buttonFav = (Button) findViewById(R.id.favButton);
        Button buttonCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        final EditText textItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.queryEditText);
        final ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String item = textItem.getText().toString();



                arr.add(item);
                //Add saved search to shared preferences
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("favs", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putString("fav", item);
                editor.commit();

                textItem.setText("");






                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        });

        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String sQuery = textItem.getText().toString();
                browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

                browser.loadUrl(getString(R.string.searchURL) + sQuery);
                browser.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);




                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        });


        buttonFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {




                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListActivity.class);



                intent.putExtra("array_list", arr);
                textItem.setText("");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                browser.setVisibility(v.GONE);
                textItem.setText("");
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

ListActivity

    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    EditText searchTxt;
    ListView lv;
    StringArrayAdapter ad;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);

        Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);



        searchTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("array_list", 0);
        String listItem = sharedPref.getString("fav", "");

         lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewItem);

        final ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>) b.getStringArrayList("array_list");

        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


        ad = new StringArrayAdapter(arr, this);
        lv.setAdapter(ad);


        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ad.items.remove(position);
                ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
                ad.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

                return false;
            }
        });






        searchTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                ad.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String query = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                String urlString = getString(R.string.searchURL) + query;

                Intent getURL = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlString));

                startActivity(getURL);




            }


        });

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

StringArrayAdapter

    import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by tobyblanchard on 11/14/14.
 */
public class StringArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    ArrayList<String> items;
    Context ctxt;
    LayoutInflater myInflater;


    public StringArrayAdapter(ArrayList<String> arr, Context c){
        items = arr;
        ctxt = c;
        myInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, parent, false);
        TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        name.setText(items.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }




    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<String> FilteredArraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (items == null){
                    items = new ArrayList<String>(items);
                }
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                    // set the Original result to return
                    results.count = items.size();
                    results.values = items;
                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                        String data = items.get(i);
                        if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                            FilteredArraylist.add(data);
                        }
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArraylist.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArraylist;
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                items = (ArrayList<String>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };




        return filter;
    }


}
```

Comment: you are always saving new inputs to this string "favs" here `editor.putString("fav", item);` am i right? and you save the on memory one to an array..that works good.. but your persistent one is always over written.. do i make sense Sir?